# How do I change this element from a hover to a click effect using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The jQuery code I'm using on my HTML isn't working. I want the "dropbtn" to be clicked on to display it's hidden contents instead of being hovered on. I tried removing all "hover" effects on CSS but the jQuery code still wouldn't work. The jQuery works fine on other codes except this one. How can I fix this?

Comment: Missing `.` dots for the classnames on Jquery

Comment: $("dropdown-content").toggle(); should be `$(".dropdown-content").toggle();`

Comment: You code is not available ,after getting the solution you have remove your code .Wrong practice .

Comment: UJS 6 Hi, sorry about that! My code is used for something important so I removed it. I didn't think I wasn't allowed to do that. Is there a reason why I shouldn't remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jQuery code was almost correct, you were just missing the `.` prefix on the class selectors.

To make the styling work in the same manner you simply need to remove the `:hover` rules from your CSS and instead use a class selector which you toggle on successive clicks of the `.dropbtn` element. In the example below I used `active`. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".dropbtn").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $(".dropdown-content").toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropbtn {
  width: 115px;
  height: 28px;
  border: solid 1px #cebbb1;
  background-color: white;
  color: #897f63;
  margin-left: -5px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn.active {
  border: solid 1px #0093dc;
  color: #0093dc;
}

#mainspan {
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 7px;
  padding-top: 4px;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  min-width: 160px;
  z-index: 1;
  border: solid 1px #cebbb1;
  width: 170px;
  margin-left: -5px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  padding: 1px 14px;
  display: block;
  color: #897f63;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #897f63;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="DROPDOWN.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <div class="dropbtn">
      <span id="mainspan">main</span>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">item 1</a>
      <a href="#">item 2</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type='text/javascript' src="DROPDOWN.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, thank you this fixed it! It seems like I was just missing a lot of things on my codes. But thank you very much for the help, it's greatly appreciated!

Comment: @confused5000 If this question resolved your issue, you should accept it.

Comment: @Armin Just did, I didn't know how to do that earlier. Thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 0):

To refer to a class in JQuery, you need to include a `.` before the class name:

```
$(".dropbtn").click(function(){
    $(".dropdown-content").toggle();
});
```